# How to have a relation to USER object of a specific ROLE in grails domain class

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-orm

I have a class as below and using **Spring Security plugin**

```
Class MyClass{

  User Manager   /** ONLY users of role "ROLE_MANAGER" **/

}
```

Basically I want to have the users of role "ROLE_MANAGER", Instead of having all the users.

How to Make it show only the users of specific role in CRUD and ensuring them while saving.

How to establish the mapping here.

Answer (score 0):

This is a validation, so you need to add a constraint. Since it's not a common constraint provided by the framework, you can use the [validator](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Constraints/validator.html):

```
class MyClass {
  User manager
  static constraints = {
    manager validator : { User userInstance, MyClass instance ->
      //get the association.
      UserRole ur = UserRole.where {
        user == userInstance && role.authority == "ROLE_MANAGER"
      }.find()
      if(!ur) {
        return 'myclass.user.invalid'
      }
    }
  }
}
```